# how to pass generic list of unknown type to class constructor

Tags: c#

The snippet below works just fine for a given method but I want to do the same during class construction.  How to do it?

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
```

Want something like this...but the constructor doesn't like the `<T>(IList<T>` part.

```
public class DTloader
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    public DTloader<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
    }
```

.......

Comment: This looks similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196357/generic-class-with-generic-constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At that point the class *itself* would need to be generic.  Something like this:

```
public class DTloader<T>
{
    //...

    public DTloader(IList<T> data)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The constructor would know at compile-time what `T` is because the declaration of the class instance would specify it (or be able to infer it).

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers given, If you want to have a non generic DTLoader you can create an abstract DTLoader and make the generic one inherit from  it

```
abstract class DTLoader
{
 //..
}

class DTLoader<T> : DTLoader
{
   public DTloader(IList<T> data)
   {
    //...
   }
}
```

This would actually give you the feel you seem to want - Have just the constructor use a generic type.

Comment: interesting -- thanks for expanding my understanding a bit!